# make text background color not herited CSS

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-color

I want to make the background for h2 the same background image of the container div not the background color inherited from this rule :

```
* {
background-color: black;
}
```

Expected result shown in this screenshot [image]

But what I got is [image]

The container div of the h2 element has an image as background:

```
.container {
background-image: url('./img/some-image.jpg');
}
```

I tried to select the h2 tag and make its background-color set to none or transparent but it did not work!.

Comment: Create fiddle please.

Comment: Your CSS rule `* { background-color: black; }` is too aggressive (catch-all rule). Be more selective when assigning the black background.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem, could you add a Stack Snippet?

Comment: You can check priorities of css classes that will apply, here a useful link: http://qnimate.com/dive-into-css-specificity/

Comment: @Éric yes but I want the background to be black by default, that's why I put it like that

Comment: @SimoneRossaini One is required to post a [mcve] here, within the question, and not any third party site.

Comment: @Rob it's same where, the concept was to post an example.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I don't understand your statement but the point remains that one is to post his code here and not a fiddle.

Comment: Yes here with snippet

Answer (score 1):

As I told you in comment, your catch-all rule `* { background-color: black; }` is too aggressive.

Is this what you are expecting?

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: lightgray;
}
.container {
  background-image: url('http://picsum.photos/id/114/400/300.jpg');
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h2>H2 Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Best regards

Comment: But I obtained h2 in a separate line from the background image!

Comment: and the background still black

Comment: Now it works but I added a selector of h2 to the css Rule: ```.container, .container h2 {
  background-image: url('https://i.picsum.photos/id/114/400/300.jpg');
}```

Comment: @SidouMahmoud, Make sure to delete this rule: `* { background-color: black; }`

Comment: Hi @SidouMahmoud, if this or any other answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

instead, of writing a direct change in background colour make a div class.

Comment: yes good solution but I should append it to each tag in my html page ?